# message: "Http failure response for http://localhost/post.php: 0 Unknown Error" & POST http://localhost/post.php net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add data to my database, I don't see my error, feel stuck.
Being junior with PHP and Angular, use php via xampp and Angular 8.

can we make 2 files for the post and get method in the php file?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  getUrl: string = 'http://localhost/test.php';
  postUrl: string = 'http://localhost/post.php';
  product = [];
  reactiveForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(),
    lastname: new FormControl(),
    city: new FormControl(),
  });

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMethod();
  }

  postMethod() {
    let myFormData = new FormData();
    myFormData.append('name', this.reactiveForm.value.name);
    myFormData.append('lastname', this.reactiveForm.value.lastname);
    myFormData.append('city', this.reactiveForm.value.city);

    return this.httpClient.post(this.postUrl, myFormData).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('resulat', this.reactiveForm.value);
    this.postMethod();
  };

  getMethod() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.getUrl).subscribe(data => {
      this.product.push(data);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  };
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
   <form [formGroup]="reactiveForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label">Name</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" formControlName="name"><br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label">LastName</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" formControlName="lastname"><br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label">city</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" formControlName="city"><br>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

**post.php**

the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error I had already resolved for the Get method but it comes back why ?

```
<?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input", true);

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $password   = "";
    $dbname     = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    //echo "Connected successfully";

    if(isset($_POST['name'])) $name=$_POST['name'];
     else      $name="";

    if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) $name=$_POST['lastname'];
     else      $lastname="";

    if(isset($_POST['city'])) $name=$_POST['city'];
     else      $city="";

     // Add User
     $sql = "INSERT INTO `test_1` (`id`, `name`, `lastname`, `city`) VALUES ('', '$name', '$lastname', '$city')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $myJSON = json_encode("New user created successfully");
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I updated my php file, now I have the following error

[image: console]

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli

Comment: Also **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Tip: Currently your PHP returns JSON when it's successful, and HTML when there's an error. This is confusing and annoying for client code trying to read the response because it won't know in advance how to parse the response. Either stick to always giving a JSON response, or always giving a HTML/text response.

Comment: Anyway, as well as the Console, use the Network tool to help you see what response you're actually getting from the server. You should be able to see the call to post.php listed there (if it's not, reload your page and run the AJAX request again). Click on that listing. Then you can see a) what headers were really returned by the server, b) what the response status code was, c) what the response body looked like. That should give you more clues about the problem. If you're still unsure, post more screenshots of that here.

Comment: Thank you for the warning I take it into account I will try to secure. @ADyson

Comment: need help please

Comment: Thanks for the update. the only way I can really see this problem happening is maybe if the PHP is crashing for some reason. Have you checked that at all?

Comment: Actually I've just seen why it's crashing - `if(isset($_POST['name', 'lastname', 'city']))` is not valid syntax. If you want to check those variables you have to check each one individually. Make sure you have PHP set to log errors. Also you should unit-test your PHP (e.g. using a tool like PostMan) before plugging it into AJAX, to iron out any bugs, then you can narrow down issues like this before adding the extra complexity of the front-end. Also you should use a code editor or IDE which highlights syntax errors - then you'd have seen this before you even tried to run the code.

Comment: I updated my php file according to your advice @ADyson

Comment: ok good. So did it work?

Comment: it works halfway I have this error,                   
                                                                       
  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: lastname in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: city in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br /> 
                                                                                          
 but the field "City" works well

Comment: `$name=$_POST['lastname'];` and `$name=$_POST['city'];` look wrong don't you think? Should be `$lastname=$_POST['city'];` and `$city=$_POST['city'];` I expect. Please make sure you double-check your work!

Comment: ooh Thank you very much, you have solved my problem. I will pay more attention to my code in the future. @ADyson

Answer (score 1):

First i'd like to suggest you read the comments under question, there are some very important answers there about SQL injection and vulnerability.

Second to answer your question. Start reading the error messages. Your error message says $lastname is not defined on line 35. This means that in your query the variable $lastname is used, but you never created the variable in your code

if you read your code you'll see this

```
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) $name=$_POST['lastname'];
     else      $lastname="";

    if(isset($_POST['city'])) $name=$_POST['city'];
     else      $city="";
```

If post lastname is set, overwrite `$name`, otherwise set `$lastname` to empty, same goes for your city statement. Meaning your only create the variable lastname if it doesn't get posted.

If you're using PHP7+ you can actually use the `??` operator (Null coalescing). which would do the isset for you, and you could write your code like this

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? '';
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'] ?? '';
$city = $_POST['city'] ?? '';
```

If you're still on PHP5+, your code is fine, but personally I would prefer the ternary operator for this, once again causing less chance for issues

```
$name = true === isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
```

Now what is very important, and that's why I said read the comments. Someone could now post values to your page with things like

```
$_POST['lastname'] = '\'; DROP TABLE test_1; \'//';
```

And if posted correctly and your permissions are incorrect (not a xss executing expert), it will drop the table. Where dropping tables is the least of your worries, the extracting of data is the real danger here.

It's therefor always wise to escape your query params, preferably you'd use mysqli or PDO's mechanisms to escape your query params by using prepared statements

IN mysqli your code would look something roughly like

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);
```

Otherwise you can at least use the native mysqli functions

```
mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr ) : string



// Add User
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test_1` (`id`, `name`, `lastname`, `city`) VALUES ('', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $lastname) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $city) . "')";
```

Also, if your ID is an autoincrement, you should either not add it to your query, or use the mysql keyword `DEFAULT` as a value instead of an empty string

Finally: Next to escaping your input, it might be wise to validate that it is what you want it to be, for example a name should theoretically not exist of only numbers?

More on prepared statements
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

More on PHP operators (Null coalescing and ternary)
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

And on a personal note, always use `{}` for your if statements, makes it more readable, and prevents mistakes in why isn't the second line executed?